# FFTW multi-dimensional FFT

Tags: fftw, multidimensional-array

I am trying to utilize the multidimensional FFT fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d from a single array of data. I have a M data points, N number of times:

```
float *input = (float*)malloc( M * N * sizeof( float ) );
// load M*N data points data
fftwf_complex *outputFFT = (fftwf_complex*)fftwf_malloc( N * ((M/2) + 1) * sizeof( fftwf_complex ) );
fftwf_plan forwardFFTPlan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d( N, M, input, outputFFT,  FFTW_ESTIMATE );

fftwf_execute( forwardFFTPlan );
fftwf_destroy_plan( forwardFFTPlan );

// Plot M data points, ignore the rest. Plotting magnitude of the data sqrtf( ([REAL] * [REAL]) + ([IMAG] * [IMAG]) )
```

The FFT results are not correct (validated through working MATLAB script), but if I just take a 1D FFT of M data points:

```
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
   float *input = (float*)malloc( M * sizeof( float ) );
   // load M data points
   fftwf_complex *outputFFT = (fftwf_complex*)fftwf_malloc( ((M/2) + 1) * sizeof( fftwf_complex ) );
   fftwf_plan forwardFFTPlan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d( M, input, outputFFT, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

   fftwf_execute( forwardFFTPlan );
   fftwf_destroy_plan( forwardFFTPlan );
}
// Plot M data points, ignore the rest. Plotting magnitude of the data sqrtf( ([REAL] * [REAL]) + ([IMAG] * [IMAG]) )
```

the result is correct. The data being loaded into the array is the same. What am I not understanding about multi-dimensional FFTs? I read through the help pages and I "thought" I was doing it right, but obviously I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

After asking around, I found my issue: fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d performs a 2D FFT which I was reading differently. I needed to use [fftwf_plan_many_dft_r2c](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs) instead, which allowed me to specify the strides and sizes to perform a 1D FFT multiple times.